# How to query an Apollo GraphQL model from Update Resolver

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I can't figure out how to access models from this resolver. I added models in the parameters of the mutation but the mutation doesn't seem to receive it as an argument; unlike queries, for example the query user: async (root, { id }, { models }) => {...} receives as a parameter the models object. How can I access models from a Mutation?

This is my resolver

```
export const FileResolver = {
Upload: GraphQLUpload,

    Mutation: {
        uploadFile: async (parent, { file }) => {
          //access model
        }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution in case someone else needs it:

```
uploadFile: async (parent, { file }, {models}) => { //code }
```